# Is there a postcss plugin which compiles scss to css(gulp)?

Tags: plugins, sass, gulp, postcss

For example, [**postcss-scss**](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss) is not a plugin but a parser, which does not compile scss to css. I know there is a [**gulp-sass**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) and it works just fine.

The reason I would like to start using a plugin for postcss is because they say [**postcss can be more than 30 times faster**](https://pawelgrzybek.com/from-sass-to-postcss/).

But it seems I can't find a plugin for postcss which would compile scss to css. Please, help.

Comment: It will be faster, but only on really, really, really huge projects. I use sass regularly when working in a corporate environment with tons of includes, files, mixins and variables, all hosted on an external SSD connected through USB 3.0 and it takes around 3 seconds for a dev build and 10 seconds when building for production. Unless build time is absolutely crucial and needs to be blazing fast (because you're depending on a lengthy workflow), I'd stick with sass. Note that getting to know PostCSS is also time that you could invest in developing.

Comment: @JonathanArbely coming up on nearly 4 years later, would you give the same advice? If so, how do you handle tree-shaking using just Sass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that PostCSS shouldn't be used together with SCSS in one workflow routine as this pretty much defeats its purpose. It's either SCSS to CSS or PostCSS to CSS.

As you already stated, there is a [postcss-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#syntaxes) parser, but that **serves the purpose of using SCSS syntax** when working with PostCSS:

> PostCSS can transform styles in any syntax, not just CSS.

Comment: Ok. So is there a way to compile scss to css using postcss and not a default gulp-sass plugin? When I use `.pipe(postcss(plugins, {syntax: require('postcss-scss')}))`, it outputs `.scss` file with `.pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))`. And I want to get `.css` file at the end using postcss only, without using `gulp-sass` plugin.

Comment: Here's my task: https://jsfiddle.net/8j6d81n2/ It outputs `.scss` files in the `css` folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start with the [default task](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#gulp) and the added [SCSS Transformations](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss#scss-transformations)? Seems like the task you linked is only part of your workflow.

Comment: If you're only just starting with CSS and aren't sure if to go with SCSS/SASS or PostCSS, I'd choose one and stick to it. Mixing is bad practive, imho. I'd stick with SASS.

Comment: @KulaGGin If you think my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the solution (correct answer).

Comment: I am either not understanding something, or it just doesn't solve the problem in question. Here's an updated https://jsfiddle.net/8j6d81n2/1/ . How do I make it to output valid .css file by only using postcss with plugins? I want to do it to improve build time, because, apparently, they say PostCSS proccesses everything in one sequence, that's why it takes less time to use PostCSS with multiple plugins than gulp- alternatives.

Comment: And regarding that mixing sass with postcss is a bad practice - it is very subjective, a lot of people would disagree with you. And I'm just not good enough to be able to debate about it:
https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/extend-sass-with-postcss

Comment: @KulaGGin The post you linked simply explains how to build PostCSS workflow around your regular SASS workflow. He is simply moving from gulp to PostCSS, but the way SASS is compiled stays the same. Which means there is no way you are saving time in compilation when it comes to SASS. Using PostCSS plugins instead of gulp plugins may save build time, but again, that difference is propably so small that it shouldn't be the reason for you to choose PostCSS. PostCSS is about extendability beyond SCSS/SASS. Not solely better build performance. Keep that in mind when building your workflow.

Comment: You still need to build SASS (e.g. gulp-sass) as usual. PostCSS won't do that for you. _It (PostCSS) can instead be used to add additional features to your workflow that Sass doesn’t provide._

Comment: I see. Well, I read that the reason why PostCSS- plugins build everything faster than gulp- plugins is because PostCSS is passing every file through all plugins in one iteration, while Gulp passes every file through every plugins one by one. So let's say we want to pass main.css through autoprefixer, cssnext and then cssnano. In Gulp it will process main.css 3 times with gulp-autoprefixer, gulp-cssnext and gulp-cssnano. In PostCSS it will process main.css only once. I don't see any reasons why there are no SASS compilers for PostCSS yet, considering there are plugins like postcss-scss parser.

Comment: You also compare PostCSS to Sass for some reason, they are different tools used for different reasons. I compare same postcss- plugins to gulp- plugins(so gulp-autoprefixer to postcss-autoprefixer), because as I've already mentioned PostCSS processes a file with multiple plugins in 1 iteration, while Gulp processes a file with multiple plugins in multiple iterations, making gulp- plugins inferior to postcss- plugins in terms of performance, from what I've read and tested myself so far.

Comment: There are autoprefixer for Gulp and then there are autoprefixer for PostCSS, cssnano for Gulp and cssnano for PostCSS, but for some reason there are sass compiler for Gulp but no sass compiler for Postcss yet, even considering Sass is probably one of the most popular plugins for Gulp.